# Desabilitar cache na navegação com Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, vraptor, cache, wildfly

Olá,

Estou usando o VRaptor 4 com Wildfly 9, e notei que nas minhas navegações em localhost, a cada refresh ou navegação entre outras páginas, o conteúdo HTML é recarregado normalmente. Porém, quando estou fazendo uma requisição para um servidor de produção, ou seja, para outro host, parece que o cache da página é mantido e somente atualizado apertando Ctrl+F5. Por ex: Se eu enviar uma mensagem para exibir um alert na view e navegar entre outras páginas, ao voltar para a mesma o alert ainda vai estar lá e só desaparecendo limpando o cache no browser.

Como posso desabilitar esse cache?